# Android Context object, Intents

Tags: android, android-intent

Why is a `Context` object reference required while creating an `Intent` object??

```
Intent i = new Intent(context,Target.class);
```

Answer (score 2):

`Context is reffred as object of Activity class so its necessary to start Another Activity from this(Context) Activity`

Answer (score 1):

Probably because to keep your data linked.. Intent keeps information and shares it where as Context keeps the whole Application together...

In programmers view.. Context has methods/fields which Intent needs for Object creation..

Answer (score 0):

The `Context` contains information about the current runtime state of the app, and is vital to the processing of `Intent`s. For example, it keeps track of the application's permissions to ensure that the app is allowed to perform the requested action.

Comment: I wanna start a new activity. So how the inclusion of context object helpful for the Android System to start a new activity??

Comment: The system still needs to know what activity is currently running (for the back stack), and your app may need permissions to invoke certain activities.